# WCF Service Deployment on an Environment which is SSO Protected. Works good locally but fails when deployed on Development Server

Tags: wcf

I get the following error when I try to run a service from the Development Server. It runs good on localhost.

The HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address.  Either supply an http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address.

Previously got the error :

Service XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="XXXXX">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled ="false" httpGetUrl = ""/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your configuration file on the service, not the client.  You'll need to post your configuration file or the code you're using to configure your service's endpoints in order for us to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: I have added the part of Web.Config which is used.

Answer (score 0):

This could be that the address of the service in the configuration file has server name "localhost"

When you copy this to severX and try to access it with a serverX address, it cannot find an address in the config file with that server name.

Answer (score 0):

You client config does not have any `<services/>` or `<clients/>` defined in it. How can you expect to make it work?